# Laravel Route Redirection Problems

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.4

I'm having problem redirecting my admin page to a Route::resource(); so that I could display my CRUD from the BookController

What am I doing wrong?

This is my AdminLoginController:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('guest:admin');
}

public function showLoginForm(){
    return view('auth.admin-login');
}

public function login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],$request->remember)){
        return redirect()->intended(route('books.index'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
}
```

BookController

```
public function index()
{
     $books = Book::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(3);
     return view('books.index')->withBooks($books);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')>name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@login')>name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/books/','BookController@index');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should update your `books` route:

```
Route::get('/books/','BookController@index')->name('books.index');
```

**OR**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
   Route::resource('/books','BookController@index');
});
```

and check your `route` name in `php artisan route:list`

update your code like:

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],$request->remember)){

    return redirect()->intended(route('admin.books.index'));

   }
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks @ADddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd 
But i'm having a problem with admin/books/create. It does not display and i'm having an error.  

I wanted to use the Route::Resource
Route::Resource('/books/','BookController')

or is the best solution for this is to declare them 1 by 1 ? like 
Route::get('/books/','BookController@index')->name('books.index');
Route::get('/books/','BookController@index')->name('books.index'.create);
Route::get('/books/','BookController@index')->name('books.index'.edit);